# How can i filter Windows Events retrieve with an XPATH where a certain value is a substring of the value?

Tags: powershell, xpath, event-log

Windows Events have an ability to filter by XPATH (which is a fast search). I have sucessfully using the PowerSHell Cmdlet Get-WinEvent filtered where a specific value is a specific value as shown below

```
$qry = "*[(EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName'] ='\Microsoft\Windows\Diagnosis\Scheduled') ]"                                   
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational -FilterXPath         $qry -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  -MaxEvents 3
```

However i don't really want to filter by a specfic task name but a substring of it, a start-with of contains or something.. for instance in the above scenario i want to do "startswith" \Microsoft\Windows\Diagnosis . However all the different techniques i've tried, that seem like standard XPATH 1.0 syntax such as

```
$qry = "*[starts-with(EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName'] ,'\Microsoft\Windows\Diagnosis') ]"
```

give an error 
*Get-WinEvent : The specified query is invalid*

Comment: This is *not* XPath -- sorry. Any true XPath answer will likely produce an error in your case. Notice that you are using the `\` character, but in XPath the `/` character must be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try the contains function:

```
$x = [xml] '<root><books><book title="Foo" /></books></root>'
$x.SelectSingleNode('//book[contains(@title, oo)]')
```

Reference for xpath string functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256180.aspx

Your's may look like:

```
"*[EventData[contains(Data,'\Microsoft\Windows\Diagnosis\Scheduled')]]"
```

Comment: That also produces the "the specific query is invalid". I'm wondering if there is a subset of XPATH going on with the filter search engine on windows events.

Comment: @klumsy I've been playing around with it a bit and its looking like the FilterXPath param doesn't support xpath functions.

Comment: Windows Event log uses a subset of xpath http://stackoverflow.com/a/8671523/567547